Python Selenium - Google has stopped working popup
Hi I am trying to do web scraping and code processing successfully, but later after some time(~after 5-6 hours) I am getting error (pop-up) as "Google chrome has stopped working".
Below are chrome_options that I am using
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("enable-automation")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
#chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True) #### NEW
#chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={None}')
# INITIATE CHROME
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-proxy-server")
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('extensionLoadTimeout', 60000)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/win64/123.0.6312.122/chromedriver-win32/chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)  

The Popup that I am getting is as follows

Anything else that I need to change in chrome_options?
Thanks in advance.

You have a lot of flags here... I wouldn't be surprised if one is causing the issue. First, do you need --no-sandbox for it to work? Second, why are you using enable-automation? Third, why are you using --disable-gpu? I could only find this thread which says it used to be a workaround for using Selenium in headless mode on Windows. And finally, your argument --proxy-server='direct://' is not doing anything (it's overridden by --no-proxy-server). I would try removing some flags and see if you get the same behavior

also the browser debug logs might contain useful info

Thanks for an update. If we need to enter any OTP in the website , ow can we do that?

Depends on what kind of OTP it is-- if it's SMS, this thread discusses some approaches
